# emacsclient --create-frame opens *scratch* even with initial-buffer-choice set

Tags: emacs, elisp

I start emacs with emacs --daemon when the computer starts up, and then open a new graphical frame with `emacsclient -c -n`.

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html:

> If you omit a filename argument while supplying the ‘-c’ option, the new frame displays the *scratch* buffer by default. If initial-buffer-choice is a string, the new frame displays that file or directory instead.

I have `(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/")` in my ~/.emacs. However, when I open a new frame, it still starts `*scratch*`, rather than `~`. I have a `~` buffer, but it's not the displayed initially.

Is there something else I need to do to prevent the *scratch* buffer (which I never use) from being created?

Even with a minimal ~/.emacs which **only** has `(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/")`, upon starting a new frame with `emacsclient -c -n`, it still opens up with *scratch*.

Comment: Odd -- when I open a client with these settings, I get the "~" buffer (although there's no `initial-scratch-buffer` variable).  Can you start up the daemon, open a client, and then check what `initial-buffer-choice` evaluates to?

Comment: I saw `initial-scratch-buffer` on another stackoverflow answer.

How do I check the value of a variable?

Comment: You might be thinking of `initial-scratch-message` (which controls that line of text at the top of the scratch buffer), but that won't be related to this question.  To check the value of `initial-buffer-choice`, hit `M-:` (or `M-x eval-expression`) and then enter `initial-buffer-choice`, which will tell you what that variable evaluates to.

Comment: Got it. I typed `(eval initial-buffer-choice)` into the \*scratch\* buffer (that showed up when launched with emacsclient -c), and evaluated it `C-x C-e`, and it said "~/" in the mini-buffer.

Comment: Huh.  If, with one graphical frame already open, you open another client the same way, do you still default to the scratch buffer?

Comment: Yep, they both startup with the \*scratch\* buffer.

Comment: Huh.  The only other thing I can think to try is to quit the daemon and restart it with a minimal .emacs init that includes only the `(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/")` line in it.  If opening a client after that puts you in the "~" buffer, then you'll need to figure out what in your .emacs file is the problem.  If it still gives you the scratch buffer, then I'm unfortunately out of ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56209/discussion-between-dan-and-dan-jones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior appears to be limited to versions before 24. In emacs 23, `emacsclient -c` (or `emacsclient -t`) always opens to *scratch*, even when `initial-buffer-choice` is set. This is fixed in emacs 24, so the solution is to upgrade.

Comment: I have `emacs 25.3` but scratch still opens. @Dan Jones

Comment: @Alper If you've set a different `initial-buffer-choice` in your `~/.emacs` file (something like `(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/")` to set it to open your home directory, e.g.), and `*scratch*` is still opening, it could be that something is failing to execute in your `~/.emacs` file prior to that line. E.g., maybe you're `require`-ing something that isn't available.

Comment: you might like to `(setq initial-buffer-choice 'other-buffer) ; as opposed to *scratch*, esp. when starting new emacsclient`